# Do 'factory' options appear on VIN report?

Tags: vehicle-identification, vin, lsd

I have a vehicle with an LSD option, where if fitted, wouldn't be visible to the naked eye. Nor would it be apparent while driving. I have looked up the VIN but the option does not seem to show up. Other forums mention that there is no way of knowing unless the vehicle is lifted up and inspected.

So my question really is- if the vehicle had the LSD option fitted, would it appear on the VIN details lookup (for example if I called the manufacturer). I would expect things like window tint, LED headlights, and what not, to not appear on the VIN look up. Just my thought. Whats the fact on this?

Comment: You can work out if it has a LSD by manually rotating the drive wheels when jacked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My car vin report specifies which options were / are fitted and also some things fitted by the manufacturer as a change of spec level.

So, listed are things like no dpf, no high-end sound system, yes for power mirrors, yes for adjustable drivers seat, no for memory seats and the list is long.

So depends on the manufacturer, but an lsd will be listed - unless like a car I worked on years ago that listed a 4 speed box and had a 5 speed fitted: an error at the factory. And yes, this was when 5 speed boxes plus reverse were a chosen option.

Comment: This is helpful. I'll be taking the vehicle in for a warranty fix on something else. Will ask them to verify lsd, then will mark as correct.